# Appium: UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 0, signal null

Tags: java, appium

Appium version : 1.6.4-beta

Appium server throws following exception:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: A session is either terminated or not started (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 22 milliseconds
os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver

I see following in appium server log:
UiAutomator] UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 0, signal null
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[Appium] Closing session, cause was 'UiAUtomator shut down unexpectedly'
[Appium] Removing session 1865dd4e-ed7e-431a-8233-0227173400a5 from our master session list
```

I dont understand why UiAutomator is exiting. Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. I was using 2 driver instances. Both were somehow ties to the same phone. So after one was created, the second instance  terminated the first one. Hence UIAutomator was exiting.

Answer (score 1):

This error looks like occurs just when the process `com.android.commands.monkey` is running. After I kill it the appium runs the test normally.
To kill it just run:

`adb shell ps | grep com.android.commands.monkey | awk '{print $2}' | xargs adb shell kill -9`

Answer (score 0):

I also see the same issue 
**UiAutomator] UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 0, signal null
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'**

But the reason was my device was disconnected, when I connect again its work fine.
Basically UiAutomator is looking for device and app screen, it if it is not display than it shows error in Appium server console.